# Convert NSTimeInterval to hours in decimals

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I'm working on an app, in which I take the difference between 2 NSdates, and get the interval in between using NSTimeInterval

```
let timediff = timeDownValue?.timeIntervalSinceDate(timeUpValue!)
```

then using my new timeDiff constant, I update my timeTotals var

```
var totalTime = NSTimeInterval()
```

Now, what I need to do from there is to convert this NSTimeInterval to a Decimal, because that's what they use to calculate the time. so for example if my interval between date1 and date2 is 30 minutes, I want my final output to be 0.5

I can't seems to figure out how

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `timediff` variable is already a decimal value for the number of seconds. To convert that into hours, divide by 3600.

```
let timediff = timeDownValue?.timeIntervalSinceDate(timeUpValue!)
var totalTime = timediff / 3600.0
```

Here, totalTime will be in hours.